# RestKit + CoreData : How to save an object locally only after the remote save is successful?

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I am using RestKit 0.10.1 with Core Data on an iOS 5.0 deployment target to build an app that interfaces with a custom RESTFul API. Since offline connectivity is important, I am maintaining a cache of the user's data in a local CoreData database on the device.

Now, RestKit is pretty awesome and it has been rather effortless to setup a RKFetchResultsTableController to easily display and persist my data. However, there is one behavior of RestKit which doesn't seem ideal and which I can't figure out how to change.

I have a model called 'Recording'. To create a new Recording, I am doing the following:

```
 Recording *r = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recording" inManagedObjectContext:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore managedObjectContextForCurrentThread]];

 r.name = newName; 

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] sendObject:r toResourcePath:@"/recordings" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader){
        loader.delegate = self; 
        loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
        loader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;  

        loader.serializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping serializationMappingUsingBlock:^(RKObjectMapping *serializationMapping){
            [serializationMapping mapAttributes:@"name", nil];

        }];

        RBMappingProvider *mappings = (RBMappingProvider *)[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider];
        loader.objectMapping = [mappings recordingObjectMapping];

    }];
```

This creates a new entity of type 'Recording' and then sends the entity to the server in a POST request. In a success case, this works great.

However, the problem is that the server sometimes rejects these creates legitimately. What I find in these situations is that there is already a local copy of the entity in the Core Data database with an id of 0 (the id is the primary key which is set by the server).

The only way to remove the local entity is to force a refresh of the local data from the server.

Is there a way to persist the object locally only once the server responds with a 2xx? Alternately, is there a way to undo the changes if the server responds with anything but a 2xx?

Thanks,

Comment: FWIW, creating the entity with 

    Recording *r = [Recording object]

as prescribed in the RestKit docs does not change the behavior at all.

Comment: Don't you have a callback method in RK with the server response? Keep a reference to the object and delete it if the upload was rejected.

Comment: @mundi That is one approach, and it may even be the more desirable one. However, I was wondering if it were possible to persist the local state only after the server accepted the payload. This would result in a lot less redundant code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, because Recording is an NSManagedObject, even your temporary instance needs to be inserted into the managed object context. @Mundi's solution of maintaining the reference and deleting it from the context after the error is the solution I would use. A bit of extra code beats a full refresh from the server.

Upgrading to 0.20.x will make this easier. The success and failure blocks that are used when sending a request make it very easy to keep this reference and delete it on failure. For example:

```
[_objectManager postObject:aMessage
                      path:@"message"
                parameters:parameters
                   success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation * operation, RKMappingResult * mappingResult){
                     // Success code here
                   }
                   failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation * operation, NSError * error){
                     [_managedObjectContext deleteObject:aMessage];
                     [_managedObjectContext save:nil];
                   }];
```